# jquery-ui autocomplete combobox change trace

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, triggers

the matter here is that I want to trigger the change made to autocomplete combobox of jquery-ui. BTW this is the combobox [Jquery UI Combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)

Here is a fiddle of what I'm trying for: [Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SuNMV/)

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You mean u'd like to trigger alert?

Comment: Basically, if the alert appears than the alert can be replaced with anything else. However Yes :) triggering alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code 
Specially else part of if condition
See [DEMO](http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8e)

```
             this.selected = valid = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (!valid) {
                        // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                        $(this).val("");
                        select.val("");
                        input.data("autocomplete").term = "";
                        return false;
                    }
                }else{
                  alert(ui.item.value);}
            }
        })
```

Comment: Nice solution, I see you've continued with shih-en chou way :)

Answer (score 1):

I add

```
focus:function(event, ui){
    alert(ui.item.value);
},
```

In your code, here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/SuNMV/4/

focus : Before focus is **moved to an item** (not selecting), ui.item refers to the focused item. The default action of focus is to replace the text field's value with the value of the focused item, though only if the focus event was **triggered by a keyboard interaction**. Canceling this event prevents the value from being updated, but does not prevent the menu item from being focused.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed additional event handling to be able to handle triggering the a change event because "selected" doesn't handle when hitting the enter key or losing focus on the input (hitting tab or mouse click).

As such, using the latest version of the jQuery Autocomplete script, I created the following solution: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cKb7U/)**

- **Enter:** Chooses the first item if menu is visible
- **Focus Lost:** Partial match triggers not found message and clears entry (jQuery UI), but fully typed answer "selects" that value (not case sensative)

How Change method can be utlized:

```
$("#combobox").combobox({
    selected: function (event, ui) {
        $("#output").text("Selected Event >>> " + $("#combobox").val());
    }
})
.change(function (e) {
    $("#output").text("Change Event >>> " + $("#combobox").val());
});
```

Hopefully this helps others who need additional change event functionality to compensate for gaps that "selected" leaves open.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
$( "select" ).combobox({ 
  select: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).trigger("change"); 
  }
});
```